# Reading x-json-stream on Android

Tags: android

I have to obtain response from server which is `x-json-stream`

Seems like it is seria of events emmited by server. I have to read it over socket though it fails with exception

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '200 OK'
```

It works over traditional get request, thought it fails with `SocketTimeOutException` after receiving several events.

What is a right way to process it? It is traditional socket, but straighforward reading it it with OkHttpClient doesn't work for it.

```
client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in type of events sent by server [Server events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Solved by usage [EventSource](https://github.com/tylerjroach/eventsource-android) implementation for Android.